# Why would GetFilesAsync return no files?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime

Why would `GetFilesAsync` return no files? I have a folder that contains images, no subfolders, and no other files. FolderPicker shows the expected folder content. However, `GetFilesAsync(OrderByName)` returns no items.
(The folder is not part of any library and is not indexed).

**Edit** - Add Code

Getting the folder:

```
var folder = await folderPicker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.AddOrReplace("PickedFolderToken", folder);
```

Accessing folder content:

```
var foldersFiles = await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName);
```

foldersFiles is empty. However, Windows Explorer and the folder picker show that it has content.

**Edit** - More info

This returns files. The only difference is the CommonFileQuery is removed.

```
var foldersFiles = await folder.GetFilesAsync();
```

**Edit** - More info

This also does not work:

```
var queryOptions = new QueryOptions(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, null)
{
    FolderDepth = FolderDepth.Deep
};

var query = folder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions(queryOptions);
var foldersFiles = await query.GetFilesAsync();
```

Remove `CommonFileQuery.OrderByName`, and it works.

My current work around is to avoid `CommonFileQuery.OrderByName` (...and maybe the other OrderBy's too).

Comment: Could you share your code?

Comment: do you have right permissions for the folder?

Comment: Added code. @Raman, I believe the code above gives me permission to access that folder. I would hope that if I did not have permission, I would at least see some sort of error/warning text in the output window.

Comment: Has your app registered to handle the types of files in the directory you're looking in?

Comment: @PeterRitchie Not that I know of. However, the above code returns files for any folder under the PicturesLibrary. (The app has permission to access the PicturesLibrary)

Comment: What would happen if you tried this: var foldersFiles = await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, "*"); OR var foldersFiles = await folder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByName, ".jpg");

Comment: I don't think those overloads exist: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.storagefolder.getfilesasync.aspx

Comment: I was referring to the fileTypeFilter. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br208007.aspx